# Angular Translations Ngnx

Tags: angular, nginx

I have translations (ngnx/translate) enabled in my new Angular app, everything works fine. Except now I want to enable the translations in the navigation bar & I can't get it to work.

nav.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar class="toolbarNav">
<a *ngFor="let link of LINKS" class="text-center" routerLink="/{{ link.route }}"><i class="fa fa-{{ link.icon }}"></i><p class="small mb-0">{{ link.label | translate }}</p></a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

nav.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent {
LINKS = [
{"label":"Home","icon":"home","route":"dashboard"},
{"label":"Diary","icon":"book","route":"dashboard"},
{"label":"Lines","icon":"plus","route":"lines"},
{"label":"Search","icon":"search","route":"dashboard"},
{"label":"Settings","icon":"user","route":"dashboard"}
  ];
}
```

The translate pipe is not working, it still just shows the EN text.. anyone?